# Move div inside new child in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to move a div (keeping all instantiated js) to a new child div from the same div?

lets say I have this:

```
<div id="container">
 /*lots of content draggables, scrolls, ..*/
</div>
```

I want to get this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="innerzone">
    /*lots of content draggables, scrolls, ..*/
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using jquery find and html selector get the html value of that selector.then append a new div and insert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: **[.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)**

```
$('#container').wrapInner('<div class="innerzone" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [**.appendTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
$("#container").append(".innerzone");
$(".innerzone").appendTo("#container");
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you will create this innerzone div dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     //created new div
     var new_div = $('<div></div>');
     new_div.addClass('.innerzone');

    var div = $("#CONTENT_DIV");
    div.appendTo(new_div);
    $("#container").append(new_div);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot:

```
$(".innerzone").appendTo("#container");
```

Here check it: http://jsfiddle.net/fS2jV/